# Word Readability Grading - 7th Grade Dictionary

Tags: readability

Has there ever been a "grading" of, say  the 30/40000 most-used words to determine the  US school grade readability level", i.e. 7th Grade, 8th Grade etc., in relation to readability of those particular words? I understand that some US Newspapers use 7th Grade - so do they actually have a "7th Grade Dictionary"? That is what I am after.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources and not related with English Language and Usage.

Comment: Vocabulary is only one aspect of reading level. Entire books are given a rating, not individual words, and there are many different [reading level systems](http://www.slcolibrary.org/kidzone/kzgrwn/pdf/readinglevelcompchart.pdf)— and I imagine a good amount of controversy about grade level equivalencies. In any case, as this question is about educational normalization and not about functional aspects of the English language, I don't think it's on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The reading level of a passage is based partly on the difficulty of its grammar and partly on the difficulty of the vocabulary.  Many schools now, including the one my daughter is in, use the [Lexile Scale](https://www.lexile.com/) to rate book difficulty.  You can go to their website and type in a passage to rate the difficulty of your text.  As your question specifically addressed vocabulary however, I point you to another useful online resource: https://www.flocabulary.com/7th-grade-vocabulary-word-list/.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary contains about 50,000 entries according to my source in amazon.de.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Merriam-Websters-Essential-Learners-English-Dictionary/dp/0877798567/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1456042007&sr=8-2&keywords=Merriam-webster+learner%27s+dictionary